# Check if one column elements are there in another master list of elements and if yes, label a third column with 1 of same index if it does exist

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

[image]

This is a data frame with 5 columns.

I was looking to solve with Python. I tried converting list_1 and list_2 into actual lists and comparing to the master list column but didn't work. Any help is appreciated! Sadly, I have only Python 2.7 at my disposal too.

```
list_1  list_2 master_list l1 l2
a        c        a        1   0
b        d        b        1   0
         e        c        0   1
                  d        0   1
                  e        0   1
```

List by list and list element to column element comparison but didn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'list_1':['a','b',np.nan,np.nan, np.nan],
                   'list_2':['c','d','e', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'master_list':[*'abcde']})
df['l1'] = df['master_list'].isin(df['list_1']).astype(int)

df['l2'] = df['master_list'].isin(df['list_2']).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  list_1 list_2 master_list  l1  l2
0      a      c           a   1   0
1      b      d           b   1   0
2    NaN      e           c   0   1
3    NaN    NaN           d   0   1
4    NaN    NaN           e   0   1
```